# slowdown on the WWAN0 line when making a voice call with the Telit LE910-EU V2 module

Tags: call, at-command, wwan, telit

Sending data over WWAN0 becomes very slow when I make a voice call. Is there any module configuration that I can do with AT commands?

Module: LE910-EU V2
Revision: 20.00.406

Below is an example of the ping I sent to the server. When the voice call starts, there may be a slowdown of up to 20 seconds and then it gets better.

```
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1637 ttl=60 time=84.828 ms 
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1638 ttl=60 time=59.415 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1639 ttl=60 time=74.042 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1640 ttl=60 time=83.787 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1641 ttl=60 time=71.408 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1642 ttl=60 time=73.111 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1643 ttl=60 time=70.802 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1644 ttl=60 time=50.447 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1645 ttl=60 time=50.973 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1646 ttl=60 time=74.719 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1647 ttl=60 time=69.276 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1655 ttl=60 time=12319.033 ms (VOICE CALL STARTS HERE)
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1656 ttl=60 time=11318.993 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1657 ttl=60 time=10318.873 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1658 ttl=60 time=9318.780 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1659 ttl=60 time=8318.660 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1662 ttl=60 time=5318.090 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1663 ttl=60 time=4321.942 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1661 ttl=60 time=6322.508 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1664 ttl=60 time=3322.046 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1660 ttl=60 time=7323.021 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1665 ttl=60 time=2322.060 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1666 ttl=60 time=1321.829 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1667 ttl=60 time=321.606 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1668 ttl=60 time=108.869 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1669 ttl=60 time=89.204 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1670 ttl=60 time=108.203 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1671 ttl=60 time=183.104 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1672 ttl=60 time=89.990 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1673 ttl=60 time=130.649 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1674 ttl=60 time=92.220 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1676 ttl=60 time=662.328 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1677 ttl=60 time=55.950 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1678 ttl=60 time=77.607 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1679 ttl=60 time=88.278 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1680 ttl=60 time=59.907 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1681 ttl=60 time=51.661 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1682 ttl=60 time=52.290 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1683 ttl=60 time=97.043 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1684 ttl=60 time=78.716 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1685 ttl=60 time=69.285 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1686 ttl=60 time=68.938 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1687 ttl=60 time=79.561 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1688 ttl=60 time=69.213 ms
    64 bytes from X.X.X.X: seq=1689 ttl=60 time=77.781 ms
```